# How to resolve java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Java compiler available for configuration options compilerClassName

Tags: tomcat8

How to resolve `java.lang.IllegalStateException`: No Java compiler available for configuration options `compilerClassName`.
I use `embedded-tomcat 8.0.46` and spring `4.3.10.RELEASE`

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Java compiler available for configuration options compilerClassName: [null] and comp
iler: [null]
        at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.createCompiler(JspCompilationContext.java:231)
        at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:578)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:363)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:716)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
    <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
    <version>4.6.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

to maven pom.xml.

Look at:
https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-web-jsp-no-java-compiler-available/

Answer (score 0):

Add the following dependency and save. You may need to restart the application.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
    <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
    <version>4.6.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```